# Live view of the state of a database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, database

I am using nodejs for my application's backend. Inside my application, I need to show live changes to certain tables in the database. Right now, user makes appropriate API calls to the backend(NodeJS) which in turn makes database calls(MySQL) to get table's current state right now(SELECT * FROM table), every 2 seconds($interval). API calls are a premium resource, in my case. Is there a better way to implement it, so that it minimizes the amount of API calls(make calls only when changes are made to a table or a database)?

The construct inside the application is quite similar to a chat room but not exactly the same. Here people look at the available rooms(created by users) and then join one/multiple of these rooms to make changes to the "tables associated with this room"(created when this room was created, by its owner)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of `WebSocket` most efficient use cases, speaking of this, Node.js come with an awesome socket library `socket.io.js`

Read more about it here : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create database triggers that update database procedures or views which are then accessed from Node.js. This is a database-centric approach, providing you with a backend agnostic solution (you could query the database from whatever you want).